# How to access mysql in virtual box to mac terminal

Tags: mysql, database, macos, virtualbox, ubuntu-server

I am running mysql in ubuntu server 18.04 in virtual box on my mac OS, assuming i have allowed remote access, and have it attached to a bridged adapter, how do i access the db from the mac terminal?

Answer (score 0):

Answer was simple, ssh and type username and ip address of your server

ssh *username*@*ipaddress*